# Are SDL windows allocated on stack or heap?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I want to create a game using C and SDL, and would like to allocate the game window on the heap. Do I need to allocate it using `malloc()` and then `free()` or does SDL do it automatically when I call `SDL_CreateWindow` and `SDL_DestroyWindow`? And is it the same for the renderer?

Comment: SDL is open source, so you can [see for yourself](https://github.com/zielmicha/SDL2/blob/373232d63fffdca74fffefab97c5e455576fbb91/src/video/SDL_video.c#L1210) that it uses `calloc` when it creates the window.

Comment: Why do you care if it's on the stack or on the heap?

Comment: If that is important to you - think about it. As stack is unwinded when function returns, said function can't reliably return something that it has placed on stack. So, the only way that could be the case is if memory came from somewhere else - i.g. if `CreateWindow` would took some memory block as parameter to place its window data there. Were that the case, calling side would have determined if that is on stack or some other place. But that is not, it takes nothing, so no way for stack placement, it just uses its internal `SDL_calloc` (which you can override).

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use `malloc()` because the library handles this for you. You only need to `free()` what you allocated yourself.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_timer.h>
 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
    {
        printf("error initializing SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(10);
    }

    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("GAME",
                                       SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                       SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                       1000, 1000, 0);
    while (gameloop)
    {
        ... do game ...
    }
 
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);

    return 0;
}
```